# Android MPandroid line charts x Axis View all the labels

Tags: mpandroidchart

Hi I am using MPandroid chart library for my android app.I was able to draw the charts and mange the date and time but I wanted to show Dayly,Weekly and monthly XAxis  I was able to show the Daily records. Is there any supporting method or option to show the whole x Axis  data I have in the array

Ex 
ArrayY(Data)
ArrayX(Dates)-Dates for the current week Starting from monday.

I have data only till Wednesday so the chart is curently showing only the xaxis up to Wednesday rest of the dates are missing and My user need to see that

Any body can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport) :

```
myChart.setVisibleXRange(0, xVals.size() - 1);
```

Make sure your xVals is not empty or this may throw an error.